# How to read a vector<strings> parameter from command line

Tags: ros, syntax, rosparam, getparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have a std::vectorstd::string parameter and I like to read the values getParam.
How does the command line syntax look to read my names param from bash.

---

e.g. **rosrun my_pgk my_node _names:=???????** 
I tried: 
_names:="max susi" 
_names:="max, susi" 
_names:="[max, susi]" 
_names:="(max, susi)" 
nothing worked :-(

---

My code looks like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> names;
n_param_.getParam ( "names", names);

//For debugging
std::stringstream ss;
for ( size_t i = 0; i < names.size(); i++ ) ss << ( i!=0?", ":"" ) << names[i];
ROS_INFO ( "names: %s", ss.str().c_str() );
```

Greetings
Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194592/how-to-read-a-vector%3Cstrings%3E-parameter-from-command-line/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2014-10-09

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the moment I solved the problem with a hack

```
std::string tmp;
std::vector<std::string> names;
n_param_.getParam ( "names", tmp);
boost::erase_all(tmp, " ");
boost::split ( names, tmp, boost::is_any_of(","));
```

now I can read it with **_names:="max, susi"**

---

Originally posted by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) with karma: 847 on 2014-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-28**:
For Indigo and newer, please refer to @peci1's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now on ROS Indigo, I can get the list to an argument as follows:

```
rosrun pkg node _param:="[1, 2]"
```

This will put a list with two numbers on the param server.

It seems to be documented here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/YAMLCommandLine . Strings would be quoted by the other type of quotes than the one used to quote the whole list.

In rospy, it works out of the box:

```
print rospy.get_param("~param")[0]
```

In roscpp, the use is also as easy as:

```
std::vector<double> v;
pnh.param("param", v, std::vector<double>());
```

Problems can arise when you want to pass the array to the node using a roslaunch file - then the clasical "`<arg>` and `<param>` policy" won't work, since roslaunch doesn't know about list types and will convert the list to a single string. Since Lunar, you may use the construct `<param name="param" type="yaml" value="$(arg param)" />` ([documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/param#Parameters_from_YAML_output)). In Indigo, you can achieve a similar result by `<rosparam param="param" subst_value="True">$(arg param)</rosparam>` ([documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam#Examples)).

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2018-01-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2018-01-28**:
`<arg name="string_list" default="[this, is, list]"/>`
`<rosparam param="string_list" subst_value="True">$(arg string_list)</rosparam>`

This shows the following error: requires the 'string_list' arg to be set

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2018-01-28**:
@2ROS0 Which ROS version? Did you try enclosing each of the three strings in single quotes?

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2018-01-28**:
kinetic, I defaulted to the hack in @Markus Bader answer. I think I did try with the quotes but I'll try again in a bit and edit this comment

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2018-01-28**:
yeah I tried with the whitelist example on the documentation you linked as is without any changes. It gives the same answer even though those are ints and not strings

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2018-01-29**:
@2ROS0 So does it work for you in the end?

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2018-01-29**:
No, it seems there is a bug somewhere. I removed everything else from my launchfile and tried with a simple `image_view` node as shown below but still same error. Is there someone that can check to see if the same error occurs to them? I am running ROS Kinetic

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2018-01-29**:
Here is my basic launchfile:

> 

> 

> ```
>    <arg name="whitelist" default="[3, 2]"/>
> ```

> ```
>    <rosparam param="whitelist" subst_value="True">$(arg whitelist)</rosparam>
> ```

> 

> 

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2018-01-29**:
@2ROS0 The `<arg>` tag has to be a direct child of the `<launch>` element, and not inside the `<node>`. Then it will work.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2018-01-29**:
@peci1 you should add the launchfile syntax to the wiki page about reading ros params if you don't mind because it is missing there

**Comment by [Andrew Price](https://answers.ros.org/users/3629/andrew-price/) on 2020-02-10**:
Has anyone gotten the

```
<param type="yaml"/>
```

syntax to work? It fails for me on Kinetic with:

```
Invalid <node> tag: Invalid <param> tag: Unknown type 'yaml'. 

Param xml is <param name="ignore" type="yaml" value="$(arg ignore)"/>.
```

The `rosparam` version does work, though.